# Setting multiple SelectedValue on WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

Note: I'm using ***Mahapps.Metro*** if some parameters seem odd.

So, I have a Model called `User`, which has a `StateId`.
Combobox is filled with `States`, so when a state is selected I put the `Id` of the selected state into `User.StateId` like this:

```
<ComboBox
    Grid.Column="0"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
    mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Select a State..."
    ItemsSource="{Binding States, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedState, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding User.StateId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

And this works just fine. However, what if I wanted to put another parameter of the selected item into the `User` model? Let's say `User` also has a property called `StateName`, and when I select a new `State`, I pass both the `State.Id` and `State.Name` into the `User.StateId` and `User.StateName`?

Hopefully this wasn't too confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Use SelectedItem and set the a State property of the User rather than setting StateId and StateName?

Comment: I haven't been really using navigation properties, but I guess this is another good reason to start doing so. Thanks mm8, as usual.

Comment: @Desomph when you select an item, the SelectedState property changed gets triggered in the view model, when that happens in your view model can't you just set the user stated and name from there?

Answer (score 2):

`SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` can only be bound to a single source property. But you should be able to bind `SelectedItem` to a `State` property of the `User` class rather than trying to set both `StateId` and `StateName`.

If the `User` class doesn't have a `State` property, you could bind to a `SelectedState` property of a view model (which it seems like you already are) that then in turn sets the `StateId` and `StateName` properties of the user. You should only bind to either `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` anyway.